# see(index) method of Python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**According to see(index) method "it returns the boolean value in true (or) false depending upon whether the text at specified index is visible or not"**

**Here is the code:--**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
txt = Text(root, spacing3 = 100, width = 50)
txt.insert('1.0',"My name is Abhishek Bhardwaj")
txt.pack()


yes_no = txt.see('1.3') # Here the cheracter at third index of the first line is visible but still it returns value in NONE
print(yes_no)

root.mainloop()
```

**Plz help me to understand how this method actually works**

Comment: `see(index)` make the specified position to be visible.  The feature you mention can use `dlineinfo(index)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the `see` method is wrong. It doesn't return a boolean to say whether the index is visible or not. Instead, it guarantees that the index is visible by scrolling so that it is visible.

This is the [official documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M160) for the `see` method:

> Adjusts the view in the window so that the character given by index is completely visible. If index is already visible then the command does nothing. If index is a short distance out of view, the command adjusts the view just enough to make index visible at the edge of the window. If index is far out of view, then the command centers index in the window.

As for how it works, I'm not sure how that's relevant. It's done deep in the implementation of the tk library upon which tkinter is built.